# Is there a way to tell if a default stream is open?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

There is a line in a library that I can't take out:

```
put oResults format "x(80)" skip.
```

I have a program that is calling the library that doesn't have a default output so this line errors out.

I know I can just send output in my program somewhere but I want to fix it so you don't have to have a output. Seek function maybe?

EDIT: 10.2b

I only get an error in unix.

In a unix environment this line:

```
put oResults format "x(80)" skip.
```

errors out.

but if you put a:

```
if seek(output) <> ? then 
  put oResults format "x(80)" skip.
```

it doesn't error.

---

in a unix environment line:

```
put oResults format "x(80)" skip.
```

errors out.

but if you put a:

```
if seek(output) <> ? then 
  put oResults format "x(80)" skip.
```

it doesn't error.

Comment: What version of Progress?

Comment: What error are you getting?  I just tried what it sounds like you are doing with a simple test program and 10.2B on Linux.  If the default output is unspecified or even explicitly closed I get no error.

Comment: What is the text of the error that you see?

Comment: "trying to write to an unopened stream". I forgot to mention that I'm running in batch mode.

Comment: That's a fairly important detail ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running in batch mode.  You should **always** be redirecting your output at the OS level when you run in batch mode.  Something like this:

```
bpro -p test.p > errors.out 2>&1
```

Not redirecting output will pretty much always lead to the error that you are seeing.

If you are embedding the bpro, mbpro or _progres -b or whatever command in a script that needs to show that output or otherwise work with it you would typically use "cat" or "tail -f" on the output file.